# Problem with generic types which extends from num and type cast from int to double

Tags: generics, dart

I have a question regarding generics in dart. I have the following dart code with a generic type parameter which extends num. In my class I want now to define a variable from type T with value zero. This seems to be not possible. Can anyone explain me why this is the case?

```
class A<T extends num> {
  T t = 0; // error: A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'T'.
  num n = 0; // works 
}
```

The problem I am facing is that I want to create a list in my class initialized with zeros.
So I can do:

```
A() {
 var list = List<T>.filled(10, 0 as T)
}
```

which works for `A<int>()` but it fails for `A<double>()` with the error message

> type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double' in type cast

Whats confusing because since Dart 2.1 it's possible to pass an int to a double variable like:

```
double x = 0;
```

So how can I solve this? Is the only option really to do a type check in my constructor and generate the list with 0 or 0.0 depending on T's type?

Comment: `0 as double` won't work for the Dart VM because `int` is not castable to `double`. `double x = 0;` does not involve any casts; the language treats it as syntactic sugar for `double x = 0.0;`, which is why it works only for integer literals.  I think that you will need to explicitly check `T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simple expression which can evaluate to either `0` or `0.0` based on what `T` is bound to at run-time. The type of an expression in Dart is determined at compile-time, and you don't know the actual type of `T` before run-time.

What you can do is:

```dart
T t = 0.0 is T ? (0.0 as T) : (0 as T);
```

If someone manages to create a `T<Never>`, then one of those casts will throw, which is probably what you want.

If you have any other value of type `T`, then you can do:

```dart
class A<T extends num> {
  T t;
  A(T someValue) : t = (someValue * 0) as T;
}
```

Generally, Dart generics (type parameters) are intended for classes which treat values of the type parameter types *generically*, the same independently of what the type argument is. What you're trying to do here is *type specialization*, not being type *generic*, which is why you don't have language support for it.

You'd probably be better off making `ANum`, `AInt` and `ADouble` classes and creating the one you want - then you also don't have to worry about `A<Never>` (or `A<Null>` pre-null-safety).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix is to add a zero value to a constructor. Something like that:

```
class A<T extends num> {
  final T zero;
  A(this.zero) : assert(zero != null) {        
    var list = List<T>.filled(10, zero);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use an actual double 0.0, not 0.

Comment: That works for doubles but then I get the error on `A<int>()` because `type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast`. I want a generic solution which works regardless of T's actual type.

Comment: We don't have union types (yet), so you'll have to think "strong and sound" for now.